# JQuery - when someone clicks text menu appears

Tags: jquery

I have some text saying "menu". It is not a button. When someone clicks on the text I want my menu/overlay div to appear.

Why isn't my code working?

```js
$(".open_menu").click(function() {
  $(".overlay").toggle();
});
```

```css
.logo {
  float: left;
}

.open_menu {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.overlay {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: pink;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="open_menu">Menu</div>
</header>

<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Just before the closing body tag I have this:

```
<script src="javascript/javascript.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The only code in the javascript.js file is the following:

```
$(".open_menu").click(function() {
  $(".overlay").toggle();
});
```

The web developer tools in Chrome says "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at javascript.js:1" What does that mean??

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: Always check the developer console first.

Comment: The web developer tools in Chrome says "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at javascript.js:1" What does that mean??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're receveiving the error because jQuery isn't defined at your `javascript.js` file. Change the scripts order. First, you need the script of jQuery, and after, you `javascript.js`, like below:

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've edited my opening post, showing that I've linked to the JQ CDN and my own file.

Comment: Didn't understand what's the problem. The `div` is appearing

Comment: So why isn't it working on my laptop? Does the website need to be live before it will work? Or can I test it on my computer before going live?

Comment: No, it doesn't need to be live to work. What browser(and version) are you using?

Comment: Chrome 67. The Dev tools says "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at javascript.js:1" What does that mean??

Comment: Your jQuery code is in a diferent file? That means that it isn't being recognized

Comment: I'm loading JQuery from the Google CDN and then I'm linking to a seperate file called javascript.js - for the few lines of code I'm writing

Comment: @Markeee, edited. I've tested, and your problem is maybe the import order.

Comment: Yes it. See my solution below

Answer (score 1):

Solution: I had these two lines of code the wrong way round. This is what it should be:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/javascript.js"></script>
```

Include the jQuery first and then my file.